# cassandra migration from version 3.9 to 3.0.X

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

we have a cassandra node with 3.9 version.
Is it possible to migrate to last stable version (3.0.11)?
(we dont use any special feature of 3.9.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read downgrade session of this guide:
https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CompatibilityGuarantees

The main part:

> Downgrading is only guaranteed within minor releases and only to the previous bug-fix release

Theoretically you can try downgrading 3.9 -> 3.7 -> 3.5... etc, but there is no grantees that this will work and will not do problems in the future. Test in some dev environment if you have to do it, or stay with 3.9...

Comment: 3.9 -> 3.0 isn't a major release. "and only to the previous bug-fix release" is probably a crucial part of the guarantee that you can downgrade between minor releases.